# sendLog() method throws exception simulator

Tags: codenameone

Crash Report binding throws exception. I see the call POST https://crashreport.codenameone.com/CrashReporterEmail/sendCrashReport in the Network Monitor only sometimes in the Network monitor and it display followign messages.This network call does not happening all the time.

Comment: This is a standard connectivity exception, if the network is flaky send log can fail

Comment: Thanks Shai. But exception will be thrown even with connectivity check Server.instance.isOffline() ? This will be thrown on the device as well? Please advise.

Comment: App is not calling https://crashreport.codenameone.com/CrashReporterEmail/sendCrashReport everytime. IS there any reason for it?

Comment: It invokes that when you invoke `sendLog*()`

Comment: I have used this code in Main class and nowhere else. I have attached the code where I have used it. Please advise.

Comment: It will invoke it when online when the app is started. I don't understand the problem

Comment: SendLog() will send the error log to the registered email for both apple and android device crashes. Please advise.

Comment: Yes, it will. I would recommend using the async version though